# search box won't stay at bottom of div

Tags: css

I've been trying to get the search box to stay to the bottom of the div but to no avail, what happens is the search box goes off the screen, I've spent the past couple hours and I'm still struggling, if someone could help me I'd be most greatful, thanks Danielle.

Edit: I forgot to add this is inside a bootstrap layout

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6">
Left<br />
Left<br />
Left<br />
Left<br />
Left<br />
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="input-group search">
<input type="text" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn" type="button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
</button>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.search {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f9beek4v/ it does work

Comment: @RachelGallen I can't see the search box in the jsfiddle?

Comment: Is it on the bottom right corner @DanielleGould. And maybe it is because you're missing the closing bracket?

Comment: @Dumisani ah, but it's not inline with the div though?

Comment: How about removing `bottom: 0;` http://jsfiddle.net/f9beek4v/1/

Comment: @Dumisani whoops!, thank you very much!!! :D

Comment: Great then, glad I could help